# How do I autorun ng serve on pc startup

Tags: angular

I'm developing an app in angular 2 and I always use ng serve to start my app running in localhost.

the app that I wanted is not going to go live.

So my question is how can I automated ng serve at startup? so that everytime I restart the pc i no need to go to my project folder and do ng serve. Please advice

Thanks

John

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a look at [ask] for tips on how to ask a useful question.

Comment: hi target OS is windows 10..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for windows 8 / 10

create file foo.bat

```
CD (project folder)
npm start
```

- Create a shortcut to the batch file.
- Once the shortcut has been created, right-click the file and select Cut.
- Press the Start button and type Run and press enter.
- In the Run window, type shell:startup to open the Startup folder.
- Once the Startup folder has been opened, click the Home tab at the top of the folder and select Paste to paste the shortcut into the folder.

Comment: Ho VikingCode thanks for the answer, as a noob i'm not very sure how you go about creating a .bat file